# javascript commands not executing after ajax loads PHP file

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a PHP script being executed by AJAX, the PHP script loads everything fine except for js scripts in the actual PHP file which I am using to close divs(if the PHP file isnt run via AJAX all the scripts work FYI)..

this is the script not being run in the PHP file by ajax

```
 echo "<script> closeOne('" . $postid . "'); </script>";
```

The JS scripts to close divs are included in the header of the page

This is the AJAX script I am using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function mainload(str)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(str);
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("loadmain").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","mainload.php?page="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that `closeOne` function works ok? Make sure `$post_id` is not null or empty string.

Comment: yes, the script executes properly if I run just the PHP file with out using ajax to run the script, thanks though.

Comment: So `echo "<script> closeOne('" . $postid . "'); </script>";` is what your PHP side script returns as a response to AJAX request?

Comment: miscupload.com/pagination.php if you scroll down and click page2, you will notice none of the divs get closed.

Comment: it looks like you're expecting your script returned by an ajax call to execute immediately, which is not what happens (by default), it's just a string.

Answer (score 0):

JS in the ajax response is not executed by default. You have to parse and identify JS statements, then run them using eval function of js. See this code as an example to start your own code:

```
var sc=xmlhttp.responseText;            
sc=sc.replace(/[\n\r\t\v\u00A0\u2028\u2029]{1,}/gm, ''); //Remove all types of White Space
sc=sc.match(/<.*?script.*?>.*?<\/.*?script.*>/gm); //divide into array, all the script tags
```

Then you will loop each of the 'sc' and run the following in the loop:

```
abc=loop_var.replace(/<.*?script.*?>(.*?)<\/script>/gm, "$1"); //remove script/open close tags and get JS only
eval(abc);
```

Comment: I am new to AJAX in general, how would I add that to my current script to make it work? Thanks for your reply by the way.

Comment: Insert that code after the following line in your original code:
document.getElementById("loadmain").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

Comment: Whats your updated code? Paste your code from inside the "if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)" block.

Comment: document.getElementById("loadmain").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
var sc=xmlhttp.responseText;     
sc=sc.replace(/[\n\r\t\v\u00A0\u2028\u2029]{1,}/gm, ''); 
sc=sc.match(/<.*?script.*?>.*?<\/.*?script.*>/gm);
abc=loop_var.replace(/<.*?script.*?>(.*?)<\/script>/gm, "$1"); 
eval(abc);
}
}
  

xmlhttp.send();

Comment: What did I tell you about the 'Loop'? I didnt give you the code to copy paste as it is. You have to loop the variable 'sc' using like a 'for' loop. Then inside it, you will use the last 2 line.

Answer (score 0):

If you add script element to innerHTML of a DOM element, JS wont run immediately.
because that script element is just added.

and that tag is not going to get parsed at all.

Ideally you should send a response in form of a JSON wrapped function.

You can send output like this from the PHP page.

```
echo "(function(){ closeOne('" . $postid . "'); })";
```

In response, you could evaluate this String containing the function using eval.

```
 codeToExecute = eval(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

then call the function,

```
 codeToExecute();
```

**Note**: sending functions from server and directly executing it using eval could be a security concern.
be careful and better use some JS libraray function to evaluate the string into a JSON object.

There will be String-To-JSON convertersin jQuery,prototype and sencha's libraraies.
Better use them or if the browser supports, JSON.parse is also a good option.

But I hope the concept is clear to you.

**Alternatively**,
You could just send the post id from server in a JSON and call closeOne on the response like this:

in PHP,

```
echo "{post_id:".$postid."}";
```

and when the response comes,

```
responseObject =  eval("("+xmlhttp.responseText+")");

closeOne(responseObject.post_id);
```

Comment: I am very lost, will look up some JSON now.

Comment: Please recommend `JSON.parse` over eval.  The JSON shim from http://json.org/ can be used as a fallback.

Comment: I have no idea where to add what, do i need external JS scripts for eval to work etc? I have jquery

Comment: I will read over this again tomorrow when im not so tired, im sure it will make more sense then.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher: What about IE ? will JSON.parse work there ?

Comment: @AmoghTalpallikar -- Depends on the version of IE (and if you are in standard or quicks mode).  That comment included the link to the shim version of JSON, which will provide the functionality for IE browsers that need it.